# how to dynamically color a node according to the groups it belongs to?

Tags: r, visualization, igraph, visnetwork

So, here we go. I have a network with several nodes. Each node may belong to different groups (see my idea below).

This is a toy example, with an edge list:

```
"from","to"
"RB1","CDK2"
"CDK2","CDKN1B"
"RB1","CDK4"
"PDPK1","RPS6KB1"
"PDPK1","PKN2"
"CDKN1B","CDK4"
"PKN2","CDK4"
```

and a nodes table with one group only (**stat** column):

```
name,stat
RB1,mixed
CDK2,up
CDKN1B,up
CDK4,up
PDPK1,up
RPS6KB1,up
PKN2,down
```

and then the code that generate the network with the attribute **stat**, that is currently used to colour code the nodes, according to which **stat** the user selected:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

edgelist  <- read.csv("edges_mod.csv")
nodes <- read.csv("nodes_mod.csv")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist,directed=F,vertices=nodes)

V(g)$color  <- ifelse(V(g)$stat == "up", "red",ifelse(V(g)$stat == "down","blue","yellow"))

data <- toVisNetworkData(g)


visNetwork(nodes=data$nodes, edges=data$edges, width="100%") %>%
    visEdges(color="black") %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout="layout_with_kk") %>%
    visOptions(selectedBy= "stat")
```

The problem here is: what if a node may belong to several **stats**?
I see two main options here:

I can create the same data frame as above but with multiple **stat** columns and colour-code the nodes according to the column which is selected. I was thinking about a [0-1] column in which the nodes that belong to that **set** are labelled with 1 and will be coloured (or ON) in the network while, the nodes that do not belong to that **set** will be labelled as 0 (and will be OFF).

```
name,statZero,statOne,statTwo
RB1,1,1,0
CDK2,1,1,0
CDKN1B,1,0,0
CDK4,1,1,0
PDPK1,1,1,1
RPS6KB1,0,0,0
PKN2,1,0,0
```

OR, I can create the same data frame as above with the **stat** columns containing a list of **sets** but I don't really see how it may work

Ideas on how to colour-code the nodes belonging to different **sets**? How can I deal with this option `visOptions(selectedBy= "stat")`?

EDIT:

I know that visOption has several possibilities for `selectedBy`. I'm trying to figure out how it applies to my needs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at [visOptions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visNetwork/versions/2.0.8/topics/visOptions), argument `selectedBy` and set `multiple=TRUE`.

So I added another attribute on your nodes as cluster

Let nodes be:

```
name,stat,cluster
RB1,mixed,alpha
CDK2,up,alpha
CDKN1B,up,alpha
CDK4,up,beta
PDPK1,up,beta
RPS6KB1,up,beta
PKN2,down,alpha
```

and edges as you defined,

Then:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

edgelist  <- read.csv("edge.csv")
nodes <- read.csv("node.csv")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist,directed=F,vertices=nodes)

V(g)$color  <- ifelse(V(g)$stat == "up", "red",ifelse(V(g)$stat == "down","blue","yellow"))
V(g)$groups <- paste(V(g)$stat, V(g)$cluster, sep=",")

data <- toVisNetworkData(g)


visNetwork(nodes=data$nodes, edges=data$edges, width="100%") %>%
    visEdges(color="black") %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout="layout_with_kk") %>%
    visOptions(selectedBy= list(variable="groups",multiple=T))
```

This should reproduce what you want to achieve!

Comment: can you please provide more details? I mean...how to modify the **stat** column? Should it be a list of lists? Does each row contain all the groups a node belongs to?

Comment: I just used your example for clarification with a column added to your nodes!